# How can I Autowire JpaRepository into wildfly's custom login module?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, wildfly

Is it possible to autowire spring jpa repository to wildfly's login module? 
I tried that:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class GeneralLoginModule extends AbstractServerLoginModule {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
                           Map sharedState,
                           Map options) {
        super.initialize(subject, callbackHandler, sharedState, options);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {
      ....
    }
}
```

but userDao is null.

Comment: have you define userdao as a bean in spring context because autowired can be use with bean annotation

Comment: yes. In apache cxf services it autowired successfully.

Comment: so problem was in apache cxf